# Custom Collection Cell Error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I am simply trying to link my custom cell class with my collection cell. I have been working on this for two days now and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have followed tutorials on this and have been successful there but can't figure out what I am missing in my own project.

```
//WORKING 
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

//Crashes
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as ChampionViewCell
```

I have this problem even when I try to create a new project without anything else in it. When ever I link my custom cell class the app crashes.

Here is my custom cell class:

```
import UIKit
class ChampionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var champImage: UIImageView!
}
```

My cell identifier is set to "ChampionCell" in the storyboard and at the top of my CollectionViewController file. I have both the view controller and the cell linked to the storyboard.

I really can't figure out what I am missing. Sorry if this is a super newb question but I have really be struggling to figure it out.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` to instantiate a custom cell, you have to register the cell class using this `UICollectionView` method:

```
func registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Just call that method in your `viewDidLoad` method and it should work.

The method should be called as follows:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(ChampionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

where `reuseIdentifier` is a variable/property containing the cell identifier.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I received two errors:
1. Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'cellClass' has no keyword argument name
2. Expected '{' in body of function declaration

Comment: @StuartCasarotto: I think you're calling that method in the wrong way - see updated answer

Comment: You were right. Thank you this makes complete sense and I am sad I didn't think to look up there sooner. Thank you. I knew it would be something simple.

Comment: Quick question: I am next trying to add a picture to my cell. I have added the picture to my Images.xcassets and am using the following code to access it ( cell.champImage.image = UIImage(named: "testPhoto") ) but keep receiving an unexpected nil. Any guess why?

Comment: Are you sure the name is spelled correctly? Can't think of anything besides that

Comment: yeah 100% sure. Every where I look it is done like this but I can't seem to get it to work. If I make it : cell.champImage?.image = UIImage(named: "testPhoto") (optional) then things run but nothing is displayed.

Comment: If it helps this is the error I get : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: No idea without more code - I suggest to create a new question

Answer (score 0):

On your storyboard, the cell's class needs to be set as `ChampionViewCell`. When the cell is dequeued, it dequeues a cell from the storyboard with the identifier given (in your case, `ChampionCell`). But the cell being dequeued is still a `UICollectionViewCell`.

On the storyboard, select the cell and then in the Inspector panel (the right side panel), select the Identity Inspector (The one that looks kind of like a newspaper). The "Class" should say "UICollectionViewCell". Change this to "ChampionViewCell".